# Minidom element insertion into xml

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have some problems with insertion data structure into xml document.But with no big success.I have file eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<marl version="2.1" xmlns="xxxx.xsd">
    <mcdata id="2" scope="all" type="plan">
        <header>
            <log action="created"/>
        </header>
        <mObject class="foo" distName="a-1">
            <p name="Ethernet">false</p>
            <list name="pass"/>
        </mObject>
        <mObject class="bar" distName="a-1/b-2">
            <p name="Voltage">false</p>
        </mObject>
    </mcdata>
</marl>
```

Basic version of my code goes like this, but seems to have no effect because output.xml is thesame as mini.xml.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import *
document = parse('mini.xml')
mo = document.getElementsByTagName("mObject")
element = document.createElement("mObject")
mo.append(element)
with open('output.xml', 'wb') as out:
    document.writexml(out)
    out.close()
```

Comment: what is the effect? the line `document = parse('mini.xml')`  produces a parse error to me: `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 14, column 0`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Source xml was badly formatted. Issue is now fixed.

Comment: if it helps: with this code `element = document.createElement("mObject")
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello"))
document.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].appendChild(element)` I got `<mObject>Hello</mObject>` as a child of `<mcdata>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new node and decorate it as needed :

```
#create node <mObject>
element = document.createElement("mObject")
#add text content to the node
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("content"))
#add attribute id to the node
element.setAttribute("id"  , "foo")
#result: <mObject id="foo">content</mObject>
```

Add the newly created node to a parent node :

```
#select a parent node
mc = document.getElementsByTagName("mcdata")[0]
#append the new node as child of the parent
mc.appendChild(element)
```